# how to implement locks in NeO4j using php side scripting

Tags: php, neo4j

Hi all I have this problem where I need to lock a particular node while I do some operations on it and after I am done with it I have to release the lock.
.
I have read about pessimistic locking in neo4j but how do I implement that like I am using jadell neo4jphp libraries.

Any help in this direction would be very appreciative we are stuck and don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Up to Neo4j 1.9 each REST request is one transaction. There is no way to have transactions living longer than a request.

In Neo4j 2.0.0-M04 (a milestone release) a transactional REST endpoint has been added, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/preview/rest-api-transactional.html. To enforce a lock there is the trick of removing a non existing property.

Answer (score 0):

So today Neo4j automatically adds a write-lock to nodes experiencing any write operations that lasts until the end of the transaction. As far as I can tell, via Cypher you cannot manually-explicitely get a write-lock on a node (at least natively), but you can do this via Java.

I've read of some hacks where you write a fake property to a node and then remove the fake property before the end of the transaction, but a better way is probably to use the popular [APOC plugin](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures), which has a selection of procedures for explicitly locking nodes which can be called via Cypher.

Learn more at [neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_locking](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_locking)